# Download a specific file from .git repo

Tags: git, github, download

How do I download one specific file from a git repo, instead of cloning the whole repository?

Is it possible to download a specific file from GitHub git repos?

Answer (score 2):

For GitHub, you can use a URL like this

```
https://raw.githubusercontent.com/antirez/redis/unstable/README
```

Or this

```
https://rawgit.com/antirez/redis/unstable/README
```

[RawGit](http://rawgit.com)

Answer (score 1):

Git doesn't work for individual files, it was designed with a different workflow in mind. You can still technically do it, but you would need to have the repo cloned first, or at least the `.git` directory. You can then checkout specific file:

`git fetch {remote}
git checkout FETCH_HEAD -- {file}`

Comment: I have wondered for so long how to do this - thanks for the answer